# Building angular into android

Tags: android, angular, firebase, cordova, cordova-plugin-firebasex

We were trying to compile this project but then this happened

```
    Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:124)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:101)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:904)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:70)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:43)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:94)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:99)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Type com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzb is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzc`.
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:89)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:60)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:64)
    ... 10 more


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /home/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/firebase-iid-19.0.0.aar/00e50672c82189861edb256e2270706b/jars/classes.jar
```

Cordova CLI version : 11.0.0
Cordova platform version: Android 8.0.0
Plugins and versions:

```
com.unarin.cordova.beacon 3.8.1 
cordova-androidx-build 1.0.4 
cordova-plugin-actionsheet 2.3.3 
cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter 1.1.3 
cordova-plugin-androidx 1.0.2 
cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.8 
cordova-plugin-ble-central 1.4.1 
cordova-plugin-cocoapod-supportx 1.7.3 
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.2 
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2 
cordova-plugin-firebasex 6.1.0 
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.1.0 
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.11.0 
cordova-plugin-googlemaps 2.8.0-20200709-2008 
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.2.0 
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1 
cordova-plugin-keyboard 1.2.0 
cordova-plugin-local-notification 0.9.0-beta.2 
cordova-plugin-mixpanel 4.7.0 
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.4
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.3 
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.5 
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.6.8 
cordova-sqlite-storage 3.4.1 
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 
uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator 4.2.2
```

By any chance do you know if there is a conflict between these plugins?
Any help you could provide us would be appreciate
Thank you so much

Comment: Try a platform remove/add

Comment: it doesn't work. Same error

Comment: Your firebasex version is really low though, is there a reason for that?

Comment: Version compatibility. Its an old project. If we use newer versions it breaks telling us we need that version. Same with others like androidx

Comment: I looked at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-iid/19.0.0, and in that single jar `com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzb` is an interface and `com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzc` a class implementing it. There is probably a conflicting definition in another dependency. I have created https://r8-review.googlesource.com/c/r8/+/66287 to give a better error message in the future.

Comment: We upgraded Android 8.0.0 to 9.0.0 and it worked...